# Can't get column with format date in dataset to database

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, date, dataset

I've googled but can't find a awnser to a problem.  I've made a vb.net application in VS2008 with a dataset in it.  I want to store a column with format date in the sqlite database.

In the immediate Window of VS I see the data of the dataset (ds):

```
?ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(2)
#2/1/2012# (Date)
```

I've use the next line:

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ds).Sourcecolumn = "ID"
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", ds).Sourcecolumn = "Date"
```

The field ID is stored into the sqlite database.  But the field Date is emtpy in the database.

In another part I import from a DateTimePicker:

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date.Parse(DateTimePicker1).Text))
```

This works.  Has this something to do with the format in the dataset?  If so. How to correct the sourcecolumn?  Or how to pinpoint the problem?

Comment: Can you try converting that date to a string and then update the database?

Comment: I've done conversions with the field(s) and at the end totally nothing came in the database.
Lookes like I've broken it...but

Now I made this line:
`sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", ds.Tables.Item("Date")).SourceColumn = "Date"`

So I added `.tables.Item("Date")`
Looks like something goes wrong in the communication towards the datebase (field goes missing).
The ID line stays the same.
If I change that into tbables.Item("ID").
Then the ID goes missing.

But problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ds.tables(0).rows(0).Item("ID") ).Sourcecolumn = "ID"
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", ds.tables(0).rows(0).Item("Date") ).Sourcecolumn = "Date"
```